# Play video from local file with tvOS

Tags: swift, url, tvos

I want to play a little video (20 seconds) when my app opens on the Apple TV. But I can't find how to implement the URL from a local file.

This is what I've got so far, but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // I know this is how to play a file from a webserver:
        // player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!)

        // But I can't find how to set the URL to a local file in the app
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("bunny", ofType:"mp4")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        player = AVPlayer(URL: url)

        player?.play()

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine. Maybe, you should try this:

> In the Project Navigator select your Project Root > Your Target >
>   Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources. Check to see that your video is
>   there, if not click the plus sign to add it.

Source: http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-play-video-swift/

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to list the most compact way along with all four hurdles:

> Import **AVKit**, Call the playVideo() function from **viewDidAppear**, watch
>   out for the **correct Bundle access** and make sure the file has the
>   **correct target membership** as stated by Ennio!

```
private func playVideo() {

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType:"mov") else {
        debugPrint("video.mov not found")
        return
    }
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

    // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = player

    // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
    present(controller, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```